# Spinner Menu - Android

Tags: android, menu, spinner

I would like to add multiple spinner bar menu in my app in android. I am a beginner in it and i created only one spinner bar. When i create the next one it doesn't work well.  tried to add next spinner here but when I did it, it displays value from the second table in the first spinner. It should be first spinner -1st table etc. Thanks in advance for help.

```java
public class SecondPan extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Spinner sspnOption6,sspn2;
    private TextView ttxOption6,ttx;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_pan);
        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.sspn);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.tab1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
        String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared two `Spinners` **sspnOption6** and **sspn2**, but you never used them. Also you have got the reference for only one spinner which id is **sspn**.

So now get reference to another id also create different `ArrayAdapters` for them, this way you will not get value of first spinner in second one for selected position.

Make theses changes.

You have already declared two spinners before onCreate():

```
private Spinner sspnOption6Spinner;
private Spinner sspn2Spinner;
```

Get reference of those views, you have earlier got only one.

```
// Check your id's from layout.
sspnOption6Spinner = findViewById(R.id.sspn_options6);
sspn2Spinner = findViewById(R.id.sspn);
```

Set `ArrayAdapters`

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> firstSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.tab1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
firstSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sspnOption6Spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> secondSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.tab2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
secondSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sspn2Spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now set listeners, both should have their own:

```
        sspnOption6Spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

```
        sspn2Spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

If you want you can set `onNothingSelected()`

Also read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner), it has all details.